# cannot find the library microsoft.mshtml in a 32 bit windows machine

Tags: c#, .net

i have developed an application which uses library microsoft.mshtml , it works fine in 64 bit machines , but is seems like the the dll is not present in GAC for 32-bit machine,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are depending on the kindness of others when you use the x64 version.  The PIA needs to be installed on the target machine.  That's normally something you need to take care of with your installer.  It is ready to get included with your installer, you'll find it back in the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\Primary Interop Assemblies` directory on your machine.

The need for an installer isn't very popular with programmers.  Always the last thing to be taken care of when the project is already late, nobody ever has time for it.  It is pretty rare to actually *need* the PIA in the GAC:

- .NET 4.0+ and VS2010+ support the Embed Interop Types option for the assembly reference.  Instead of having to depend on the PIA, the compiler can now include the interop types in the program itself.  And only the ones it actually uses, greatly reducing the deployment size.  **Always** favor this option, simply set it to True in the Properties window.  In itself already a great reason to update your VS version and move up to .NET 4 if that's the hangup.
- Most sane deployments don't actually need the assembly in the GAC.  Simply change the Copy Local property on the assembly reference to True.  You get a copy of Microsoft.mshtml.dll in your build directory, copy it along with your EXE and the rest of your DLL dependencies to the target machine.

Comment: the  copy property for the library does not allow me to set  it to true

Comment: I'll have to pull that tooth I guess.  So do you see the Embed Interop Types property and is it already set to True?  Then of course there is no point in setting Copy Local so it is disabled.  And you don't need the PIA.